# Django forms not being tranlated

Tags: django, gettext

I am trying to use `gettext` in Django to translate forms. But for some reason, it does not work. It only works when I set `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ar'` Other parts of the template are being translated successfully.
**Django version 3.0.7**

**Form difination**

```
class productform(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(label=gettext("Name"))
description = forms.CharField(label=gettext("Description"),required=False)
def is_valid(self):
    if not super().is_valid():
        return  False
    if product.objects.filter(name__exact=self.cleaned_data['name']).exists():
        return False
    return True
```

**How the form is used**

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">{% trans "Save" %}</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Any idea where I failed to get it to work?

Comment: use `ugettext_lazy` for form field labels

Comment: Thanks @AndreyMaslov it's now working correctly